# How can I organize my laravel project's github repository so that users can easily install and run it?

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-5

Five months ago I created a pretty extensive Laravel Blog Management system. I am now at a point where I am looking for a job and would like for potential employers to be able to easily install and run my project to check it out. I want to include instructions in the readme.md on how to get it started but I've just realized that I can't figure out how to run it myself!

Here is the repository: https://github.com/colesam/Laravel-Blog

Here is what I've tried:

```
git clone git@github.com:colesam/Laravel-Blog.git
composer install
php artisan serve
```

This copied the repo into my xampp/htdocs directory and ran it. XAMPP is currently running with MySQL and Apache running.

The console responds by telling me it's being served on localhost:8000. Unfortunately I receive an error message on the actual html doc:

[image: a busy cat]

What is going wrong with my project and how can I make this as easy as possible for my potential employers / anyone who would like to download and check out my project?

Comment: A good start would be to set the `APP_DEBUG` variable in your `.env` file to true. Then you can start debugging step by step. Also from my experience, recruiters don't usually actually install the projects, so you might want to set it up on a publicly accessible server instead, to save them time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy actually. Takes about ~5 minutes. Here are the steps:

1. Clone the project
2. Create a database
3. Copy `.env.example` to `.env` and set the correct database credentials
4. Run `php artisan key:generate` to generate the app key
5. Run `php artisan migrate` to create the tables
6. Run `php artisan serve`

And you're done.

[image]

Comment: I was under the assumption that the database was already created when the laravel project was set up and resides in the database directory. Once I create a database, where do I put it and how can I seed it using the db seeds I made? Additionally, do I need to do anything with the php artisan key?

Comment: You need to create a database in MySQL - that part can't be done with Laravel, then need to run `php artisan migrate` to create the database tables. I actually forgot that step (included it now). Then you can run the seeder with `php artisan db:seed` to insert the data.

Comment: If I am using a product like XAMPP is this database already set up for me?

Comment: I assume you got it working? Otherwise, I believe XAMPP comes with phpmyadmin which is probably the easiest way to create a database. The MySQL comes preinstalled, but you need to create the databases on your own.

Comment: Yes it's all working now, unfortunately some other problems are coming up in regards to loading js and css resources from the public folder, but I'm going to create a new question because it's beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: Hmm are you serving with `php artisan serve` or are you trying to access it through `localhost`? The `php artisan serve` option worked for me out of the box. But yeah, probably best to ask a new question with the details included

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169994/discussion-between-samuel-cole-and-devk).